Column accepting null strings and struct values for delta table
I'm working with unstructured data, JSON files, in Databricks using Pyspark.
Basically I have some json files which contains a field.
"Field1" which is a regular StructType, but when it contains no values it shows up as null.
Problem is that when inserting data for those fields that are null they fail because the table i'm inserting to has that column schema as StructType, but seems like I'm trying to insert a null string.
What could I do to handle this issue? I need to be able to store both kind of values in the same column in the json format
Below an example of the file.
{
    "Field1": {
            "c1": "a",
            "c2": "30",
            "c3": 1
            },
    "Field2": "abc"
}
{
    "Field1": null,
    "Field2": "abc"
}   
{   "Field1": {
            "c1": "b2",
            "c2": "3",
            "c3": 5
            },
    "Field2": "cd"
}
    

Created the table by infering schema, and trying to write with a
df.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchema","true") command. Expected to be null value column when the "Field" contains null, but got the following error
Error showing is: Failed to merge fields 'Field1' and 'Field1'

you could use placeholders. for example "-" for blanks.

By replacing null fields with structs with - as values?
I think I understand your point, but could you provide an example? Thanks

yes,  although, you might need to edit the code because it is not valid JSON (needs commas)...

You don't need the .option("mergeSchema","true") option when you write the data.
Suppose you have a Delta table with a struct column Field1. You can write your dataframe to the table as below:
%sql
CREATE TABLE spark_catalog.default.struct_data (
  Field1 STRUCT<c1: STRING, c2: STRING, c3: BIGINT>,
  Field2 STRING)
USING delta
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'Type' = 'MANAGED',
  'delta.minReaderVersion' = '1',
  'delta.minWriterVersion' = '2')

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType

# Declare the JSON schema.
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField(
            "Field1",
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField("c1", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("c2", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("c3", LongType(), True),
                ]
            ),
            True,
        ),
        StructField("Field2", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

# Read the JSON data:
df = (
    spark.read.format("json")
    .option("multiline", True)
    .schema(schema)
    .load("<path_to_json>")
)
df.show()

+----------+------+
|    Field1|Field2|
+----------+------+
|{a, 30, 1}|   abc|
|      null|   abc|
|{b2, 3, 5}|    cd|
+----------+------+

# Write the data to the table.
df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("struct_data")

# Verify the data:
spark.sql("select * from struct_data").show()
+----------+------+
|    Field1|Field2|
+----------+------+
|{a, 30, 1}|   abc|
|      null|   abc|
|{b2, 3, 5}|    cd|
+----------+------+


EDIT:
If you cannot define the schema by hand, here's one way to do it for the Multiline JSON file. This should be a one-time activity.

Use jq to convert the file into a JSONL file  as:

jq -c '.[]' multiline_source.json >> jsonl_source.json


Read this file as a csv file:

df = spark.read.format('csv').option('sep','Õ').load("jsonl_source.json")


Get the Schema for the JSON file.

from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select("_c0").rdd.map(lambda x: x[0])).schema


Hi, thank you very much this seems to work when I specify the schema.
But for this case the schemas are very hard to define as the file contains more than 30 fields and struct fields are not always the same.
What I was trying to do was reading the files infering the schema and I think that's where the issue comes from. In some cases the df.printSchema() shows the column wrong as a string and sometimes it reads it correctly as a struct.
Would there be any way to either create easily the json schema or by working only with the infer schema to inforce reading those columns as structs?

Unfortunately, I don't think this will work without defining a schema for the file. Updated my comment to show how I'd fetch the schema of the JSON file - This should be a one time activity to generate the schema - hackish, but should do the work.
